# When do I need to use malloc in C++?

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt4

If I can create a QString in C++ like:

```
QString s = "my string"; // or,
QString *s = new QString("my string");
```

Then, when will I event need to use `malloc`?

Comment: This question reinforces my opinion that learning C before C++ gives you a better understanding of the language.

Comment: @Jesse: How so? Learning C before C++ will only help here *coincidentally*, since `malloc` comes from C. But this has nothing to do with C directly, it's just another memory function in C++.

Comment: @GMan: I understand your point. If you are able to identify what comes from C and also what C++ tries to improve upon from C without studying C, then that is fine. However, for someone that has not programmed in C, it is more difficult to understand the following question: "Why *shouldn't* you use malloc?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You never need to use `malloc` in C++.

Ok, now that I've said *never*, one exception is when you are using C code that for some reason or another takes ownership of a block of memory you give it and later calls `free` on a pointer to that memory to deallocate it.

I have never seen that before (I don't usually use C libraries and I don't know how common that scenario is), it's just a contrived situation that I can think of where using `malloc` would *not* be optional, because it's undefined behaviour to call `free` on a piece of memory created by `new`.

Comment: @VladLazarenko touche :) "C" and "old" go together in my mind, but that's wrong and just a habit I can't seem to shake. I fixed it.

Comment: Although I can't give examples, I've heard people say that it is sometimes more efficient to overwrite the new operator with malloc. Any comments?

Comment: To correct myself there, I meant overloading, not overwriting. There's a difference.

Comment: Ah, now I get your point. Yes I meant overloading operator new and operator delete, but I didn't phrase it that correctly. I should have said "overloading the operator new by using malloc" or something alike. My intentions were clear though :)

Comment: @xcrypt I'm sorry, English is not my native language so sometimes tiny discrepancies can really throw me off. I'll delete all my comments since they were pointless.

Comment: @SethCarnegie No problem, after all I made the mistake so it's good  that you pointed it out :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's almost never a need to use `malloc` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Never!

`malloc` allocates uninitialized memory. You rarely need to do that in C++. Most of the time you create and destroy objects using `new` and `delete`.

There are a few situations where you do need to allocate unintialized memory, for instance when implementing dynamically sized containers such as `std::vector` and `boost::optional`. But then the C++ way is not to use `malloc` and `free` but to do

```
void* p = operator new(1000);
...
operator delete(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ mostly handles allocation and deallocation for you, unlike C.

In other words, you shouldn't ever have to use `malloc` for your example.

Comment: FTFY: C++ **obscures** memory allocation and deallocation for you, unlike C.

Comment: @matt: -1 for that comment. There is nothing obscure about `new` and `delete`. If you can't understand those, then you should not be programming in either C++ or C.

Comment: @MSalters: I never said there was. In fact I didn't mention `new` or `delete` at all.